# Passing arguments to Lambda function using Slack

Tags: parameter-passing, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-api

I have a Lambda function in which I want input from Slack.I am not able to pass variables from Slack to Lambda function.

Any suggestions would he helpful.

Thanks

Comment: yes. Slack invokes API Gateway which in return triggers Lambda

Comment: Integration Request body mapping templates is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: I need to pass 4 input variables to Lambda function from Slack channel. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: how to do that. I don't know much about it

Comment: I am making POST request. However I want to send arguments to Lambda function via slack slash command. Eg, /cmd arg1 arg2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this, but I googled it. Looks like this is such a common request that AWS set up a lambda blueprint specifically for slack. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-slack-integration-blueprints-for-aws-lambda/
https://www.thorntech.com/2017/03/serverless-slack-chatbot/